Cannot connect to the database using the DB Browser Plugin for IntelliJ community edition
I am encountering an error when trying to connect to my SQLite DB file. I want to create a simple web app to add to my portfolio which shows I can use an SQL DB. When I click on test connections, It says I am properly connected. Once I close the connections window I get the following error message:
Unable to attach database file database.db: [SQLITE_CANTOPEN] Unable to open the database file (unable to open database: database.db)

I am using IntelliJ Community edition with the DB Browser plugin.
I have tried double checking the file paths and they seem correct. I will attach a picture for my project file path as well. You can see the code below:
public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(CarScreenerApplication.class, args);



            String url = "jdbc:sqlite:src/main/database/database.db";

            try {
                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
                System.out.println("Connected to the database.");

                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Error connecting to the database");
            }

    }

I also tried executing the schema.sql file for my project which has no effect on the database file. Additionally, when I try to run the schema file it says that to schema is selected, but that of course is because the file I want to run is supposed to set up the schema:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cars (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    make TEXT,
    model TEXT,
    year INTEGER,
    incidentsPer1000 INTEGER
);

I feel like the issue is how I am using the DB browser connection but I have never used this tool before so I am not sure. In picture 2 you see under properties that autocommit is off, I read that turning it on could fix this but when I tried that it still said I was not connected.
Database connection settings
Database connection settings 2
Database connection settings 3
Database file path
